# Sinatra + SQLite + ActiveRecord (strings can not be saved)

Tags: sqlite, activerecord, sinatra

I have a problem with saving strings in database. Integers are going well. I have a model `Payment`with one field :command(String). This is from console:

```
p = Payment.new
p.command = 'test'
=> "test" 
p.save
=> D, [2014-10-20T15:30:43.383504 #2229] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  begin transaction
=> D, [2014-10-20T15:30:43.386985 #2229] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  commit transaction
=> true 
Payment.last
=> #<Payment id: 1, command: nil>
```

**My app file**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'activerecord'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'

set :database, 'sqlite3:qiwi_exline_development.sqlite3'

get '/' do
  @payments = Payment.all
  haml :index
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :command
end
```

**My schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141020092721) do

  create_table "payments", force: true do |t|
    t.string "command"
  end

end
```

Interesting moment: If i change string to integer in schema -> integer values are saved without any problems.

Comment: remove `attr_accessor` from model. In the case of `ActiveRecord` models, getters and setters are already generated by `ActiveRecord` for your data columns. `attr_accessor` is not needed. `attr_accessor` — is a deprecated method of controlling mass assignment within `ActiveRecord` models.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was so simple! Please put your comment as answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `attr_accessor` from model. In the case of `ActiveRecord` models, getters and setters are already generated by `ActiveRecord` for your data columns. `attr_accessor` is not needed. `attr_accessor` — is a deprecated method of controlling mass assignment within `ActiveRecord` models.